# Worksbook saved with stream is broken

Tags: c#, .net, aspose-cells

recently I was trying to save Aspose.Cells.Workbook to stream with

```
private Stream GetWorkbook()
{
    // processing workbook here
    // ...
    // saving to stream
    return workbook.SaveToStream();
}

private void Save()
{
    using (stream = GetWorkbook())
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
}
```

But when I'm trying to open generated .xlsx file Excel sends me an error that file is corrupted.

Comment: What is the file size of the xlsx file? If you rename the xlsx file to `a.zip` and open it up, is it a valid zip file?

Comment: @mjwills Nope, it's not. The actual template file size is 120KB, generated file is 1KB.

Comment: Does putting `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` before the `CopyTo` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SaveToStream()** method will only save your workbook in **XLS format**. So you should not use this method but use the following code to save your workbook in memory stream object. It should fix your issue.

**C#**

```
//Load your Excel file
Workbook wb = new Workbook(yourFile);

//Create memory stream object
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

//Determine the save format
SaveFormat svfmt = (SaveFormat)wb.FileFormat;

//Save the workbook to memory stream
wb.Save(ms, svfmt);
```

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose